# Pass a string together an annotationView

Tags: ios, nsstring, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In my map there are many annotationView, each with their own image,
the data of annotationView are taken from different tables in a database.
When I select un'annotationView I want to display another viewController and to do this I need to pass the table name, which is a string. How do I?
I tried but I get this error:

```
  No know instance method for selector 'setNameTable:'
```

This is the code in MapViewController.m

```
  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
   <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
      //....

      if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AnnotationCustom class]]){

       static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

      MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*) [mapView 
                   dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];


       annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                  reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];  

      if ([self.name isEqualToString:@"MyTable"]){

            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_myTable.png"];

               [annotationView.annotation setNameTable:[NSString 
                   stringWithFormat:self.name]]; //the error is here
               //nameTable is a property of AnnotationCustom class 


            }else{
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_myTable.png"];

                [annotationView.annotation setNameTable:[NSString 
                   stringWithFormat:self.name]];//the error is here
                 //nameTable is a property of AnnotationCustom class 

            }

          //.......


       }
```

In the delegate method I must pass the string

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

      AnnotationCustom *customAnnotation = (AnnotationCustom *)view.annotation;
     [customAnnotation setNameTable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name]];

     NSLog(@"The name table is  %@",customAnnotation.nameTable); 
     /*the name is wrong, the string self.name is relative to last table open and not the 
      table  selected */


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I added a cast to annotationView in the delegate method:

```
  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id 
  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
          //....
        static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*) [mapView 
               dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];


       annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                              reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

       //I add in this position the cast
      AnnotationCustom *customAnnotation = (AnnotationCustom *)annotationView.annotation;

      if ([self.name isEqualToString:@"myTable"]){

            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_myTable.png"];
                customAnnotation.nameTable = self.name; //I assign this the property


           }else{
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_myTable.png"];
                customAnnotation.nameTable = self.name; //I assign this the property

            }
      }
           //.......
   }
```

In another delegate method:

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
        calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

        AnnotationCustom *customAnnotation = (AnnotationCustom *)view.annotation;

        NSLog(@"The name Table is %@",customAnnotation.nameTable);      
        //the result is correct
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation property of the annotationView object is of class MKAnnotation which doesn't know anything about a 'nameTable' property..

Try this:

```
AnnotationCustom *annotationCustom= (AnnotationCustom *)annotation;
[annotationCustom setNameTable:[NSString stringWithFormat:self.name];
```

Comment: Is no longer the same error, but I can not pass the string when selecting  the annotationView

Comment: Have a look at the answer above from Anna Karenina. The annotations' properties should be set at the point of their creation.

Answer (score 0):

Although casting will give you access to custom properties and methods, you generally should not be *setting* properties or calling methods on the `annotation` object in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Since you are also trying to set the property to some *class-instance-level* value (`self.name`), there's also no guarantee that its value is in sync with the `annotation` the delegate method is currently being called for.

What you should do is **set the annotation's property when you create the annotation** and before calling `addAnnotation` or `addAnnotations`.

Later, in the delegate methods (such as `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`), you can again retrieve the custom properties using casting.

Comment: I tried to retrieve the custom property using casting, but out the name wrong. The string is relative to last table open and not the table selected. I added the code to show

Comment: I set the property of customAnnotation when I created it, in viewDidLoad, but in delegate methods is not visible

Comment: In the delegate methods, do not call setNameTable.  Just read the property.  Show the code where you create the annotation.